# Allowing break/new line from Text area in Regex

Tags: asp.net, regex

Hey I have the following regex `0-9-a-z-A-Z-@-.-:-/-_- -\r\n-\s-` ,

which is fine but i also want to allow new lines/break from data from text area so I can retrieve the next line.

So lets data is like this

```
Geography - Higher - A1
Irish - Higher - A2
Maths Ordinary - B1
English - Higher - B1
Business - Higher - B1
French - Higher - B1
```

My current script is stopping at "Geography - Higher - A1" I need to get to next line.

PS : What I am doing is using a program called Text Template Parser which requires the regex

Answer (score 3):

It's hard to say because some editors (web or otherwise) do line breaks differently.  Try using just '\n' or '\r'.  Sometimes it just one of them.

Try this to test what you're editor is using.

```
.*\n.*

.*\r.*
```

Comment: Thanks for replying..I tried [-\r-\n-\r\n-\s-\S-\r--A-Za-z0-9.- -\n-vbCrLf-\r\n-]+\.[A-Z]\b\s*$ but still no joy